# Connecting Microsoft Surface Precision Mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I am having some issues getting my Microsoft Surface Precision mouse to work under Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying this on a fresh install and I am using a Bluetooth Low-Energy module since my computer doesn't offer native Bluetooth. I have been able to connect and use another generic Bluetooth mouse.

My issue is that it appears to connect:
[image: appears to connect]

However, when I click, it states that its connected, but not paired:
[image: connected, not paired]

How can I get my mouse to work?

Answer (score -1):

1. Install these two packages (possible already installed): `sudo apt-get install bluez blueman`
2. Open with supersu: `sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`
3. Uncomment in line 67 uncomment `[Policy]` and uncomment in line 89 `[AutoEnable=false]` and change it to `[AutoEnable=true]`
4. Open with supersu: `sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules` and uncomment the whole line (it's only one)
5. Save all up and restart the system
6. When you logged in click on the blueman bluethooth menu (thats new)
   [image]
7. Click: `Local Services -> Pan Support -> at the bottom of the window, choose blueman (dhclient) -> Apply`
8. Hold the button on the bottom of the mouse until the blue light blinks on and off, and wait to get into pairing mode. Once paired, you’ll see it in *Devices*.
9. Highlight it and right-click the device entry for Designer Mouse and choose Trust

Note: if the mouse speed is too fast, change it in the mouse settings!

Comment: This solution does not work. Pairing still fails, but you can use the Mouse very well until you close the Pairing dialog. After that it stops working entirly. The same mouse using the same dongle with windows 10 works perfectly fine. Also 50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules does not seem to exist in the recent versions of bluez, but adding it does not change failed pairing at all.

Comment: no didn't work for me either.